# Django : url main page

Tags: django, url

I want to add a main page with a login but I have the error

> A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.

what does it means ??

url:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^§', main_page),
    url(r'^mainView/$', mainView.as_view()),                   
    url(r'^material/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', MaterialDetailView.as_view(), name='material_material_detail'),
)
```

view:

```
def main_page(request):
    template = get_template('registration/main_page.html')
    variables = Context({ 'user': request.user })
    output = template.render(variables)
    return HttpResponse(ouput)
```

Comment: Enable DEBUG=True in the settings.py. So that you can know the actual issue.

Comment: I have DEBUG=True if i just write  url(r'^$', mainView.as_view()), it works but I have the main panel not a page with login..

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you meant

```
url(r'^$', main_page),
```